# PostgeSQL Python

Tags: python, postgresql

Проблема в том, что не могу нативно подключиться к postgre базе. Подключение через DSN работает, но когда пытаюсь прописать всю строку подключения сам, ничего не выходит.

```
import pyodbc
import random
import time
from datetime import datetime

#cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=PostgreTest;PWD=1234')
conn_str = (
    "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};"
    "DATABASE=postgres;"
    "UID=postgres;"
    "PWD=1234;"
    "SERVER=localhost;"
    "PORT=5432;"
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

При этом код ошибки вообще не понятен:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\TestProj\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][\xc4\xe8\xf1\xef\xe5\xf2\xf7\xe5\xf0 \xe4\xf0\xe0\xe9\xe2\xe5\xf0\xee\xe2 ODBC] \xc8\xf1\xf2\xee\xf7\xed\xe8\xea \xe4\xe0\xed\xed\xfb\xf5 \xed\xe5 \xed\xe0\xe9\xe4\xe5\xed \xe8 \xed\xe5 \xf3\xea\xe0\xe7\xe0\xed \xe4\xf0\xe0\xe9\xe2\xe5\xf0, \xe8\xf1\xef\xee\xeb\xfc\xe7\xf3\xe5\xec\xfb\xe9 \xef\xee \xf3\xec\xee\xeb\xf7\xe0\xed\xe8\xfe (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Но при подключении через DSN, в котором прописано все тоже самое, работает как надо.
Почему мне надо подрубиться именно через строчку? Есть другая софтина которая через ДСН подключаться не умеет, а ее использовать нужно обязательно.

Перед тем как написать сюда вопрос, предварительно нагуглил по этой проблемы, проблему решить не удалось.

Comment: Нашел решение путем установки Devart ODBC Driver for PostgreSQL, только теперь запросы не выполняются)

Comment: `[#<Encoding:Windows-1251>, "[IM002] [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Источник данных не найден и не указан драйвер, используемый по умолчанию (0) (SQLDriverConnect)"]`, для тех, кому интересно, что за экранированная жуть в сообщении об ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задайте следующие параметры

> DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};

Comment: Нет, положение это не спасло. Но по вашему примеру решил попробовать другой драйвер "SQL Server", собственно результат тот же, но думал дольше.